# Prevent NullpointerException on primitives attributes for a Java class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Let's assume we have a class like this:

```
class Check{
    private int ammount;

public Check(){
  //Notice default empty builder
}

//Setters and getters
```

Now, how can we prevent NullPointerExceptions when calling on the getter for a primitive datatype?

```
//We cannot do this
...
if (myCheck.getAmmount() == null){
 ....
}
```

So, how can we prevent a NullPointerException on this cases?

Comment: For your reference type variables, you can avoid NullPointerException by checking prior to evaluating `if (myCheck.getAmmount() != null){ //do your job }`. Don't use mycheck.getAmmount() before testing for null.

Comment: I misunderstood the question at first, hope my answer helps :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primitive types can't be null. So methods returning primitive types can't return null.

Comment: So, what could I expect if I do something like this: String s = String.valueOf(check.getAmount());

Comment: You should do `if (check.getAmmount() != null) {
String s = String.valueOf(check.getAmount());
}` - @chntgomez

Comment: check.getAmount() will not return null never. It will return always a primitive value. If amount is not initialized it will contain the default value 0.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I've wanting to know. The default values on the primitive datatypes!

Comment: Solve it elegantly by Optional.ofNullable(check).map(c -> String.valueOf(check.getAmount())).orElse("")

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility of a `NullPointerException` in the first place from a primitive data type.  There is nothing to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

Primitives like "int", "boolean", "float", "double" cannot be null. Are you referring to "Integer", "Float", "Double" instead?

Comment: Let me ellaborate further, What would happen if I do something like this: String s = String.valueOf(check.getAmount()):

Comment: OK, in this case it depends on the method "String.valueOf" implementation. For your example (using "int" primitive) the default value of "int" is zero (0), then the "s" value will be "0"

Answer (score 0):

You must read all the question, the conclusion is not null for primitive types, they have a ***default value***, but! don't misunderstand primitives such as

**int, double, char, byte,**

with *classes* such as

**String, Integer, Double**..

Those could return **null** to you. **In that case,** I recommend to read all the posible answers here [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)